# within a class , call x function to return a list value from y function. python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

main code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from refract import random_move

while True:

rw = random_move(5000)
rw.track()
pointsv = list(range(rw.points))
fed = input("you need scatter/ plot: y/n ")
if fed == 'y':
    plt.scatter(rw.xv,rw.yv, c= pointsv ,cmap=plt.cm.Greens, s = 2)
    plt.show()
if fed == 'n':
    plt.plot(rw.xv,rw.yv, c = [0,0.5,0.5], linewidth = 2)
    plt.show()
```

class definition

```
   class .....................

  from random import choice

  class random_move():
      def __init__(self,points):
    self.xv = [0]
    self.yv = [0]
    self.points= points
    
def track(self):
        xv= getstep()
        yv= getstep()
        
def getstep(self):
    dxv = [0]
    while len(dxv) < self.points:
        xd = choice([1])
        xva = choice([3,4,5,7,8,9])
        xt= xd*xva
        if xt == 0:
            continue
        nx =  dxv[-1]+xt
        dxv.append(nx)
        
    return dxv
```

final output:

```
  error: 
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------


    NameError: name 'getstep' is not defined
```

Comment: It's hard to tell for sure with the broken formatting, but it looks like you are trying to call the *method* ``getstep`` as a *global function*.

Comment: sry! I am new to forum . under a class random_move , I created two functions  and I call a function from another one to request a list value. after that I import the class in a separate file and when I call the function from there, nameError was thrown into the screen

Answer (score 1):

try it;

```
def track(self):
        self.xv= self.getstep()
        self.yv= self.getstep()
```

You have to call the method of the class via the object from the class or via the class itself passing an object of that class. In your case, to call track method, you should call `self.getstep()` or `random_move.getstep(an_obj_of_the_class)`